# Could someone explain why the answer is "Incorrect" instead of nothing?

Tags: python, boolean

> Question: What will be displayed by the following code? Code is as follows:

```
isCorrect = False 
print("Correct" if isCorrect else "Incorrect")
```

```
Answers: 
 A. Correct
 B. Incorrect
 C. nothing
 D. Correct Incorrect
```

Comment: Why do you think it should be nothing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the lazyness is out of hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression inside the `print` call is a one-line `if` of the form `<true value> if <condition> else <false value>` (somewhat similar to a ternary operator in C or Java). Since `isCorrect` is `False`, it returns `'Incorrect'`.